# postgresql Create Table based on columns of remote data

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I want to copy a table from a remote database to my local `Postgres` database. I face these constraints:

- I'm not the owner of the remote database, I only have select privileges.
- The table is a result of a `view`.
- Therefore, `pg_dump` is out of the option, I believe.

I find out that I can use `COPY` with `STDIN` and `STDOUT` in `Postgres`. However, `COPY` works only if the table on the local database is already created (if I understand correctly).

There are about a thousand columns in the table I want to copy. Obviously, I don't want to type in all the columns and data types in `CREATE TABLE`. What's a good solution for this?

The `COPY` commands (if table is created) I use are as follows (Python Interface):

```
copyremote = "COPY (SELECT * FROM {}.{} {}) TO stdout".format(dbname, tbname, condi)
copylocal = "COPY {} FROM stdin".format(tbname)
command = ['psql', '-h', remotepg, '-U', username, '-p', port, '-d', database, '-c', copyremote]
p1 = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(['psql', dbname, '-c', copylocal], stdin=p1.stdout,   stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()
return p2.communicate()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to export the table to a csv, rsync the csv to your local machine and import the csv back to your postgres by so,

Import and Export with a header to preserve the datatypes of the table as so.

> Import CSV to table with Header for columns present in first row of
>   csv file.

```
COPY <TargetTableName> FROM '/path/to/csv/SourceCSVFile.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV HEADER
```

> Export a table to CSV with Headers present in the first row.

```
COPY <SourceTableName> TO '/path/to/csv/TargetCSVFile' DELIMITERS ',' CSV HEADER;
```

If you have access to the table alone on the remote postges DB:
you could use the -t option to pg_dump only the particular table

```
pg_dump -U your_rolename -d <database_name> -t <table_name> > file.sql
```

Comment: Thanks. I would like the data types to stay the same (double precession, text etc), given the null entries. I worry about data types may change if translated through csv. (I know it is the case through pandas read_sql).

Comment: copy does not create a new table, so in order to keep the data type the same, you need to create an empty table with the same data type(schema) on your local postgres as that od the production and execute the copy command with HEADER. That way the data is not altered.

Comment: "you need to create an empty table with the same data type(schema) on your local postgres". That's exactly my question, how?

Comment: pg_dump -U your_rolename -d <database_name> -t <table_name> --schema-only > file.sql , assuming you have access to the remote table only  u can take a pg_dump of the single table and incase u need no data but only the schema use the --schema-only option.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, here is the solution I'm using:

- create a foreign data wrapper
- then CREATE TABLE (LIKE your_foreign_table)
- then the COPY commands above can go through

Hopefully this can be useful for someone in similar situations.